# static file loading problems on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pythonanywhere

i'am trying to deploy restframework on pythonanywhere so i can use it in for my android project
but the issues  here that the restframework page is shown whitout a css or js files
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImW94.png

i tried evrey solution on stackoverflow but nothing work !
i collectstatic file using

```
python manage.py collectstaticfile
```

i set up

```
`STATIC_ROOT='/home/ssmedicament/api/static/'`

`STATIC_URL = '/static/'`
```

Comment: I would suggest you to follow a video tutorial from beginning and cross check with your code

Comment: Did you ever tried by typing **python manage.py collectstatic** ?

Comment: What's the *Output* of typing **python manage.py collectstatic** ?

Comment: Did you set static files mappings on your PythonAnywhere Web page at the 'Static files' section? If so, check if you have correct path for the directory you're mapping etc.

Comment: yes guys,i i followed all the tutoriel step by step so yes i did pyhton manage.py colelctstatic and i set up files mappings on my pythonwhere webpage but nothing work

Comment: Try going through the debugging steps on this PythonAnywhere help page: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingStaticFiles

Comment: ty so much for your effort